# Unable to extract the hidden layer values during neural machine translation in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to look at the code in translate.py and seq2seq_model.py and unable to find a way to extract the hidden layer values in tensorflow.

Comment: The weights, or the activations?

Comment: I am trying to look for both weights and output of the hidden layer before its fed onto the output layer.